# Error while parsing empty array in RestKit

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{"projekt":{
    "id":18,
    "projectname":"test",
    "dokumente":{
        "id":1190,
        "name":"rootfolder",
        "information":{
            "folder":[
                {
                    "id":1191,
                    "name":"folder 1",
                    "information":""
                },
                {
                    "id":1198,
                    "name":"folder 2",
                    "information":{
                        "folder":[
                            {
                                "id":1199,
                                "name":"folder 2 1",
                                "information":""
                            },
                            {
                                "id":1199,
                                "name":"folder 2 2",
                                "information":""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}}
```

Basically it is a recursive folder structure. I have RKObjectMappings for project, information and folder. Parsing goes well until `information=""` is reached. RestKit now tries to call

```
value = [self.sourceObject valueForKeyPath:relationshipMapping.sourceKeyPath];
```

in RKObjectMappingOperation, line 442. This fails because the sourceKeyPath is `folder` which is not available in this `information` element. This leads to a `NSUnknownKeyException` and parsing stops.

What I want is that RestKit just ignores the information element and sets it to nil. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to set `[informationMapping setIgnoreUnknownKeyPaths:YES];`. If that is set, the exception is ignored and the value nil. Nice!

Comment: What if the empty array is null, e.g. "information":null. I tried setIgnoreUnkownKeyPaths:YES, but it doesn't seem to handle null objects. Any ideas?